# TypeError: 'list' object is not callable to do multi- indexing

Tags: python, list, pandas, dataframe, zip

I want to get multi-index dataframe.
In work, i got the error "TypeError: 'list' object is not callable"

Here is my situation

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L5HqC.png)

Plz answer me to help

Thank you

Comment: did you use list as a variable name before in the current code?

Comment: Please see how to provide a [mcve]. We are looking for some of your input data as _text_, along with the code you tried and the error you've received, _all_ as text. Not images, or links to images. Thanks!

Comment: @Kalyan you are definitely right. I used list as a variable name so that it does not work! Thank you so much!

Comment: @coldspeed It is the first time i wrote in stack over flow. sorry about that

Comment: @eunchongshin, i have written an answer with some more explanation, check it out

Answer (score 0):

You might have used list as a variable before in the code. 
here is an example code

```
a = list()
a.append(2)
print(a)

list = 1
print(type(list))
#Here you would see that the type of list is integer
#To get back the type list,just delete the reference as below
del list
print(type(list))
#Now it will print that its of type list
```